# A better way to see this relation concerning Ricci tensor components

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

If given a metric of the form $$ds^2=\alpha^2(dr^2+r^2d\theta^2)$$ where $\alpha=\alpha(r)$, then can one immediately conclude that $$R_{\theta\theta}=r^2R_{rr}$$ where $R_{ab}$ is the [Ricci tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature), without doing any explicit calculations? I can show that this is true by the long-winded way of computing both explicitly, but it would seem that there may be a more elegant way?